# How do I group by and count rows in a query AFTER adding a new column using a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has several columns including `state`. I want to write a query that adds a  `region` and then counts the number of rows grouped by `region`. I have written a `case` statement to add a `region` in a query -

```
  select region = case
    when state = 'MD' then 'East'
    when state = 'CA' then 'West'
    else 'Outside US'
    end
   from my_table;
```

How do I now group by region and count the rows. Before add the new `region` column, I could easily count by `state` using

```
     select state, count(*) as Count from my_table
      group by state
```

However now that I have added a new column, I am unsure how to count by the new column.

Comment: You can add your case to your group by as well, so group by state, (YOUR FULL CASE statemnet)

Comment: `select region, count(*) as CountRegion from (
select case    when state = 'MD' then 'East'
    when state = 'CA' then 'West'
    else 'Outside US'
    end as region from my_table) a group by region`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to repeat the `CASE` **expression** in the `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN state = 'MD' THEN 'East'
           WHEN state = 'CA' THEN 'West'
           ELSE 'Outside US'
       END AS region,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM dbo.my_table
GROUP BY CASE WHEN state = 'MD' THEN 'East'
             WHEN state = 'CA' THEN 'West'
             ELSE 'Outside US'
         END;
```

An alternative method, which I often prefer, is to define the value in a `VALUES` table construct, or a CTE/subquery. For example:

```sql
SELECT V.Region,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM dbo.my_table mt
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN mt.state = 'MD' THEN 'East'
                               WHEN mt.state = 'CA' THEN 'West'
                               ELSE 'Outside US'
                          END)) V (Region)
GROUP BY V.Region;

WITH Regions AS(
    SELECT CASE WHEN state = 'MD' THEN 'East'
                WHEN state = 'CA' THEN 'West'
                ELSE 'Outside US'
            END AS region
    FROM dbo.my_table)
SELECT region,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM Regions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `region` in the `from` clause using `apply`:

```
select v.region, count(*)
from my_table t cross apply
     (values (case when state = 'MD' then 'East'
                   when state = 'CA' then 'West'
                   else 'Outside US'
              end)) v(region)
group by v.region;
```

That allows you to reference it in both the `select` and the `group by`.

In your case, though, you might find that a `join` works better for such assignments:

```
select coalesce(v.region, 'Outside US') as region, count(*)
from my_table t left join
     (values ('MD', 'East'), ('CA', 'West')
     ) v(state, region)
     on v.state = t.state
group by v.region;
```